# Aura Kingdom - Help I can't change my secondary password

Tags: aura-kingdom

I played AK a while ago and know I want to come back and play it again...

But I don't know what my secondary password is...
Any help on changing or just seeing what my secondary password is?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, there is no way for you to see the secondary password, nor is there an easy way to have it reset. The only way I've noticed, is to send a ticket in, through the support system.